# Hydrogen ground state energy calculation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, hydrogen

We want to find the energy of a hydrogen atom ($Z=1$) in the ground state
$$
\psi_{100} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-r}\ \ \ \ \ \ (\mbox{atomic units})
$$
with Hamiltonian
$$
H = -\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2-\frac{1}{r}
$$

Then

$$ 
\begin{align*}
\langle \psi_{100}|H|\psi_{100}\rangle &=\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi  r^2\sin\theta\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-r}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dr^2}-\frac{1}{r}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-r} d\theta d\phi dr \\
&=\int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^\infty \frac{r^2e^{-r}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-r}-\frac{1}{r\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-r}\right)dr \\
&= 4\pi \cdot \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \left(-\frac{r^2}{2}e^{-2r}-re^{-2r}\right)dr \\
&= 4\left(-\frac{3}{8}\right) \\
&= -\frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

However, I've read everywhere that $E = -\frac{Z^2}{2n^2}$, and so for a hydrogen atom in the ground state we should have $E=-\frac{1}{2}$. So why am I getting $-\frac{3}{2}$? I've double-checked with Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies in assuming that 
$$
\nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \cdots
$$

This is not the case, you need to use
$$
\nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+\cdots
$$
Then will you obtain the correct answer of $-1/2$.